# mimic object oriented ansi c use functions pointer inside structures or use functions outside

Tags: c, oop, ansi-c

i'm trying to write oop in c but faced with two ways how to do it:

```
#ifndef __TREE_H__
#define __TREE_H__

#include "types.h"
#include "interface.h"

typedef struct _tree_t tree_t;

tree_t* tree_create(int (*compare_fn)(void *o1, void *o2),
                    void* (*copy_fn)(void *o),
                    void (*dealloc_fn)(void *o),
                    iallocator_t *iallocator);

void tree_delete(tree_t *t);

void tree_add_object(tree_t *t, void *o);

void* tree_fnd_object(tree_t *t, void *o);

void* tree_rmv_object(tree_t *t, void *o);

void tree_print(tree_t *t, void (*print_fn)(void *o));

void tree_balance_DSW(tree_t *t);

#endif /* __TREE_H__ */
```

or second:

```
#ifndef __TREE_H__
#define __TREE_H__

#include "types.h"
#include "interface.h"

typedef struct _tree_t tree_t;

typedef struct _tree_t
{
    void (*add_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void* (*fnd_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void* (*rmv_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void (*print)(tree_t *self, void (*print_fn)(void *o));
    void (*balance_DSW)(tree_t *self);
   
    void* private;
};


tree_t* tree_create(int (*compare_fn)(void *o1, void *o2),
                    void* (*copy_fn)(void *o),
                    void (*dealloc_fn)(void *o),
                    iallocator_t *iallocator);

void tree_delete(tree_t *t);

#endif /* __TREE_H__ */
```

So i can't recognize what way more flexible and better in aspects of design
could anybody give me an advice?

Because now it is difficult to understand what will be better

Comment: The first one is definitely more common. The second one adds a ton of overhead to the `struct` itself, as it has to carry function pointers with it (which also prevent potential compiler optimizations such as inlining)

Comment: [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may provide some additional content on what is good and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in between. It will save a lot of memory for each tree object and allows calling methods in a bit more C++ way.

Just introduce `tree_ops_t` struct which will allow sharing the interface between all `tree_t` objects:

```
typedef struct tree_t tree_t;

struct tree_ops_t {
    void (*add_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void* (*fnd_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void* (*rmv_object)(tree_t *self, void *o);
    void (*print)(tree_t *self, void (*print_fn)(void *o));
    void (*balance_DSW)(tree_t *self);
};

struct tree_t {
    const struct tree_ops_t *ops;
    void *private;
};

static const tree_ops_t tree_ops = {
  ... set all callbacks here
};

tree_t* tree_create(...) {
   tree_t *t;
   ...
   t->ops = &tree_ops;
}
```

Now the methods are called like this:

```
t->ops->add_object(t, NULL);
```

BTW.

The syntax for types derived from function types can be a bit prettified with a help of `typeof` extension (a feature in upcoming C23).

```
void (*balance_DSW)(tree_t *self);
```

becomes

```
typeof(void(tree_t)) *balance_DSW;
```

Arguably, it may be easier to read especially for returning complex types.

Moreover, when passing a function pointer as parameters you can take advantage of "function decay" mechanism where a function type is transformed to a function pointer type. For example

```
void print(tree_t *self, void (*print_fn)(void*));
```

is the same as:

```
void print(tree_t *self, void print_fn(void*));
```